# Parallelization of independent matrix diagonalizations

Tags: matrix, parallel-processing, linear-algebra

I have a set of four matrices which are of modest size - each has a size which is roughly 1000x1000. I need to diagonalize these four matrices, but for my problem, this needs to be done many times with a different set of four matrices each time. To speed this up, I would like to find a way to parallelize the diagonalization of each set of four matrices, since they are independent and my (naive) expectation is that it would be faster to diagonalize each on separate cores rather than iterate through the set of matrices and diagonalize them in serial.

A solution using numpy is fine for the purposes of this question; I am using a specialized package for this particular computation, but any illustration of how to do this kind of calculation in parallel would be helpful, I think.

Comment: What did you tried so far? It seems embarrassingly parallel. There are many related questions on how to parallelize embarrassingly parallel computations on S.O. and many tutorial/doc on it too including the standard documentation of CPython (see multiprocessing, multithreading, joblib etc.). Please consider threading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)